# Converting an Int to a BCD byte array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, bcd

I want to convert an int to a byte[4] array using BCD.

The int in question will come from an device id and his needed to speak to an device via serialport.

Is there any pre-made function that does this or can you give me a simple way of doing this?

example:

```
int id= 29068082
```

would output:

```
byte[4]{0x82, 0x80, 0x06, 0x29};
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2448303/87698. Apparently, there's no built-in BCD support in the .net Framework.