# Working with BCD

Tags: c#, byte, arrays, offset

I am trying to Get a Byte[] from a offset, from FSUIPC. FSUIPC gets and sets information in Flight Simulator X.
The offset:

```
private Offset<byte[]> RadioNav1Set = new Offset<byte[]>(0x311E, 4); //not sure about the 4
```

The documentation:

`NAV1 standby frequency, 4 digits in BCD format. A frequency of 113.45 is represented by 0x1345. The leading 1 is assumed.`

So I need to get the 4 digits behind the x. I have tried these 2, both with no luck, the value is `115.70` and the result for test1=`112` and for test2=`5488`

```
byte[] test1 = RadioNav1Set.Value;
            short test2 = BitConverter.ToInt16(RadioNav1Set.Value,0);
            txtSetCourse.Text = Convert.ToString(test1[0] + " " + test2);
```

test1 only changes when changing `.70` from `115.70` and test2 changes with random increments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the documentation you quote, the value you should use to set a frequency of 115.70 appears to be 0x1570.

Comment: Yes I know, but this is about getting the value, It is a better approach on how to later write to the value.
But Still, how do I change a number (1570) to 0x1570?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107026/converting-an-int-to-a-bcd-byte-array) should help there.

Comment: to be honest I don't really understand that answer..

Comment: It shows how to convert a binary value (an int) into its BCD representation - isn't that what you were having trouble with?

Comment: No because first I don't need to convert from Int to BCD, but the other way. Second, I don't know what integer value I should use to get the correct BCD, using the BitConverter gives the Integer, I believe, but just doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: http://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/4917
This is what I think I want to achieve, how to get the Hexadecimal I guess, not that experienced with binary code

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701043/c-sharp-byte-to-bcd-and-bcd-to-int) then.