# Converting trackbar value to byte

Tags: vb.net

```
 abrirporta()'opens serial port
        Dim sq As Integer = TrackBar3.Value

        byte2 = CByte(sq Mod 100)

        'set byte1 to be the right one
        Select Case sq
            Case 0 To 99
                byte1 = 0
            Case 100 To 199
                byte1 = 1
            Case Else
                byte1 = 2
        End Select

        ' Create the byte array with the calculated values
        Dim a1() As Byte = {&HFE, &HFE, &H94, &HE0, &H14, &H3, byte1, byte2, &HFD}

        Label1.Text = byte1
        Label4.Text = byte2
        Label5.Text = TrackBar3.Value

        ' Send the byte array to the SerialPort
        SerialPort1.Write(a1, 0, a1.Length)


        fecharporta()'closes serial port
```

I need to send byte1 and byte2 over serial. It should be just a number between 0 and 255 but sent as 2, 55. The problem is that the values on the other end jump around. I can send the values as fixed and they are received ok, but when I send them this way is like it is lost on the way.

Cheers

Comment: "I need to send byte1 and byte2 over serial. It should be just a number between 0 and 255" Okay...but `byte1` can only ever be 1,2, or 3 from the Select Case statement....and `byte2` can only ever be a number between 0 and 99 inclusive because of the mod operation. Explain better how byte1 and byte2 relate to the 0 to 255 you described in words.

Comment: The value 255 needs to be sent as two separate values. One as 0 to 2 the other 0-99. The track bar sets the value, I need to convert them to two separate values before sending. The radio on the receiving end receives the values but ex. if jumps from the value 63% to 78% when I send the values 1 99 and the value 2 00. It should not jump, but it is like there are values missing between 199 and 200.

Comment: What is the min/max set on your TrackBar? Does it correctly give you back a value between 0 and 255? How do we know that you've formed `a1` correctly? Where do all of those other values come from? How do you know if it's being read correctly by the device on the other side? What is happening in `fecharporta()`? There are so many things we don't know about your setup. How can we possibly help you?...

Comment: I have almost no experience in programming and before I was just using a select case for every value, yes it is shameful but I don't know any other away. Thank you.

The a1 is ok, it works fine if sent over as a1() As Byte = {&HFE, &HFE, &H94, &HE0, &H14, &HA, &H0, &H4, &HFD} the part of fecharporta and the start one is just to open and close the serial port. The trackbar is set to 0-255

Comment: In your original code, the 4th value from the right side is `&H3`. In your previous comment, the 4th value from the right is `&HA`.  Which is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. That value changes the target but the code behaves the same way. I just don't understand why when the value is sent that way the receiver acts different. Is like it jumps values but it does not.

Comment: Looks like the ICOM cat protocol, specification is [here](http://www.w4cll.com/info/ICOM/CI-V/CI-V%20manual.pdf). It does a decent job pointing out that you have to encode data values in BCD. Right now with the trackbar at max you don't send &H2+&H55 but &H2 + &H37 which the radio converts as 237/255 = 93%. Example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448303/converting-a-int-to-a-bcd-byte-array

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to put this as an answer as I dont have enough rep points to add an edit yet.

First, you can get rid of the case statements by using your Mod

byte2 = CByte(sq Mod 100)
byte1 = CByte((sq - byte2) \ 100)

byte2 = 55
byte1 = 2

The normal protocol is little endian, so your byte array should look like this.

Dim a1() As Byte = {&HFE, &HFE, &H94, &HE0, &H14, &H3, **byte2, byte1**, &HFD}

This should sort out the 'jumping' too, if I am correct about the endian method.

#Note the \ in the divide, this forces absolute integer and does not round up, should not be relevant, but I always use \ when using byte or integer division to avoid any errors.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it behaves the same strange way. The value sent from 0-255 is converted on the radio from 0-100% and for some reason it jumps every time the byte1 changes from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 2. And for some reason it does not reach 100% and is left in 92%. But if I send Dim a1() As Byte = {&HFE, &HFE, &H94, &HE0, &H14, &H3, &H2, &H55, &HFD} it will go to 100%. I just don't get what the difference is from sending the values as byte1 and 2 and send it as Dim a1() As Byte = {&HFE, &HFE, &H94, &HE0, &H14, &H3, &H2, &H55, &HFD}.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, want to thank everyone but finally found out what was wrong.
I was sending the values as hex and it should be decimal. That explains why it jumped some values because the hex had values like 1C that are not decimal.

Was solved by adding the line:
Dim decimalValue As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(byte2, 16)

and replacing byte2 by decimalvalue.

Cheers.